# Move the (linked to item with edit menu) ellipsis options to a different column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

I know there are already some solutions relating to this on the website but I can't seem to make this work within SPD 2013? I'm also not sure if it's exactly the solution I'm after.

What I'd like is to be able to move the ellipsis button that allows for viewing, editing, workflows etc to another column. The problem with the title column is that I'd like to keep it on a site column instead of just a list column.

I don't know if this is at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the Link to Item with Menu functionality on a field other than Name (Title for lists), you can modify the CAML in Designer. Add the following to the field in the `<ViewFields>` element: `ListItemMenu='TRUE'`. For example, your title field would like like:

```
<FieldRef Name='Title' ListItemMenu='TRUE' />
```