# Ellipses has disappeared in sharepoint list

Tags: list

I have noticed recently that the ellipses or the (...) menu has disappeared from my sharepoint list. How to show it without any codes? 
It used to appear next to list items. after I have modified the view, it disappeared...

Comment: Found the solutio here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108747/move-the-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-ellipsis-options-to-a-different-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that the column in view `Title (linked to item with edit menu)` is checked in `Columns` section while editing view.

Comment: ya you're right, this solved my question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108747/move-the-linked-to-item-with-edit-menu-ellipsis-options-to-a-different-column